# Handle a POST request in ASP.net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code works to handle a get request:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(double lat, double lon, string type) {
    // do stuff
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Now I replace GET with POST in my `$.ajax(` request and I'd like to do something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(double lat, double lon, string type) {
    // do stuff
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The only thing that works is this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(FormDataCollection form) {
    // do stuff
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Edit: Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'api/building',
    data: {lat: location.lat, lon: location.lng, type: type},
    success: function(data) {
        ItemChunk.GetByCoordinate(new Coordinate(location.lat, location.lng), true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Show your full `$.ajax()` code.

Comment: What it your intention to name one action `POST` and the other `Post`?  I think WebAPI uses convention to map the verb to the action - does the capitalization matter?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Sorry, that was a typo. I tested it with `Get`and `Post`.

Comment: Have you added the [HttpPost] attribute to your method?

Comment: The action being named `Post` should be sufficient.  Have to tried to create a class that contains the properties that you are passing in instead, and then adding the `[FromBody]` attribute?  e.g. `public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyGeoClass data)`

Comment: @ThomasLindvall The third example works without `[HttpPost]`. The second example (which is what I want) works neither with nor without `[HttpPost]`

Comment: BTW, what is the error response?  Is it a 404 or something else?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes, it's a 404: `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`. The `MyGeoClass`approach leads to a method call, but all properties of the class are default values (0.0 and null).

Comment: @Toast have you tried debugging with a route debugger? Like http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to a complex type:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Coordinate cord)

public class Coordinate
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

From what I understand, it should just work.

Comment: Thank you, this does work for me. I'm wondering though why the direct method paramters work with get requests but not with post requests...

Comment: Not entirely sure. I suspect it has to do with request headers. `GET` sends query string parameters. `POST` sends back form data.